# Keyboard layout changed in RStudio but nowhere else

Tags: r, keyboard, rstudio

Since yesterday I am encountering this strange error in RStudio. The keyboard-layout has changed completely. However, only in RStudio and nowhere else.

```
y became the z button
- became /
( became *
) became (
= became )
? became _
```

how can I resolve this issue?
I am running RStudio 1.1.383 and ran the 
    sessionInfo()
command. I got this output in the consol:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
Error in x[["Version"]] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  DESCRIPTION file of package 'yaml' is missing or broken
```

Comment: Please provide `sessionInfo()` and RStudio version.

Comment: i ran the sessionInfo() command, this is what I got:
    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    Error in x[["Version"]] : subscript out of bounds
    In addition: Warning message:
    In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
    DESCRIPTION file of package 'yaml' is missing or broken

I am Running RStudio1.1.383

Comment: Edit your post with the outputs.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too and I followed the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/66561/how-to-avoid-keyboard-layout-automatically-changing-on-windows). I never did it on purpose so I will have to wait and see if it happens again but hopefully that helps.

Comment: The same thing happened to my, using the "ALT" + "SHIFT" Trick, to use many cursors. Thank You very much, the instructions helped a lot.